# Spring is not creating the bean for @service annotated class when one of its method is annotated with @transactional

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

The spring application is failing to start as it could not find a bean for a class annotated with a @Service to be autowired in a configuration class. But it is only occurring when I am annotating a method in the that particular service class with @Transactional. Why this is happening?

Comment: please share a start log

Comment: Please attach a sample of code

Answer (score 0):

While you annotate your class by @Transactional spring use AOP and if your class is final and has no interfaces it cannot create a proxy on your class.